# How to change Mobaxterm session password

Tags: mobaxterm

Hi there so I basically forgot my MobaXterm master password and I managed to change it yay!

now I came down to another Problem my session relied on the old password so how can I change it as when I go manage credential I cant change it or show password as my software version is the free version.

I have tried changing it and all but no avail.

Please help me

Answer (score 6):

you try to reset password of `mobaXterm` pleases follows this steps

- **step 1**
  find location of `mobaXterm` files like:
  `C:\Users\admin\Documents\MobaXterm`
  go to this location
- **step 2**
  find file like : `MobaXterm` is a configuration file just open it any text editor
- **step 3**
  change like: `[Misc]`
  `PasswordsInRegistry=0` if is 1 then set 0
  and save file and restart `mobaxterm` your password will be reset.

enjoy

Comment: For me PasswordsInRegistry was set to 0, I changed it to 1 and then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a reset Master Password tool available :
https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/resetmasterpassword.html

But `PasswordsInRegistry=1` works
If you reset your master password, all your connection passwords previously saved in MobaXterm will be lost.